# Passing current user as parameter to external url using GET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, get, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm building an app using ASP.NET, MVC 5 and Identity 2.0.

When a user clicks on one of the buttons in the navbar, I capture the current user and its security stamp and pass them as parameters to an external url using GET. Just like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User != null)
   {
      <li class="menu-item">@Html.ActionLink("External URL", "ExternalUrl", "Home")</li>
   }
...

public ActionResult ExternalUrl()
{
    var user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var userName = user.UserName;
    var par1 = user.SecurityStamp;

    return Redirect("http://externalurl/access.asp?" + "userName=" + userName + "&par1=" + par1);
}
```

This does work and it solves my problem, but looks ugly as hell. I'm new to web programming and I assum there must be a better/prettier way of doing this. How?

Comment: well, you could hold the UserName and SecurityStamp inside the claims identity, so you wouldn't have to hit the database all the time... but it seems like an opinion-based question. I don't think it is ugly as hell

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own ActionFilterAttribute to 'inject' an object containing all the user attributes that you need.

Your UserViewModel would be:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    public string SecurityStamp {get; set;}
}
```

The filter implementation:

```
public class LoggedUserParameterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

            // Get the User (you have to adjust your code here)                
            var user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

            // 'Assemble' your logged user with all the needed information
            var userViewModel = UserViewModel {
                UserName = user.UserName,
                SecurityStamp = user.SecurityStamp
            }

            // Create an optional action parameter 'loggedUser'
            filterContext.ActionParameters["loggedUser"] = userViewModel;
        }
}
```

And finally you could 'inject' the loggedUser parameter in any action method like so:

```
[LoggedUserParameter]
public ActionResult ExternalUrl(UserViewModel loggedUser)
{
        return Redirect("http://externalurl/access.asp?" + "userName=" + loggedUser.UserName + "&par1=" + loggedUser.SecurityStamp);
}
```